# How can I covert text file from some thing like this "ãÍãÏ ÓíÏ ãÍãÏ ÇáãÍÌæÈ" to arabic text

Tags: conversion, arabic

I've a text file that containe an arabic text but when I try open it by np++ or notPad I find somme thig like 'ãÍãÏ ÓíÏ ãÍãÏ ÇáãÍÌæÈ' how can I restore my original file?

Think you..!

Comment: You are going to have to supply Notepad++ the font (i.e. language pack) required to render the language.  Within Settings and Preferences select Localization on the General tab and choose your prefered language in the pulldown menu displaying the languages.

Comment: thinx. but, I want convert som text like "ãÍÌæÈ" to text like "جميل"

Comment: Given the correct localization, if the application supports it, the text should simply open as the correct language if it is actually the correct data. If the data is not correct, then being told it is to be a different language will mean nothing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you have some sort of encoding issue. Paste it into a text editor (Notepad++/Sublime) and tweak around with the localisation settings.
You might need to change the document type from UTF-8 to Unicode/play around.